# make4ht and dvisvgm generates a '.svg' file that contains text regarding using option '-dNEWPDF'

Tags: make4ht, macos, dvisvgm, texlive-2023

I'm generating `.svg` files with `mahe4ht` and `dvisvgm`. The `.svg` is generated but contains text at the beginning regarding the use of option `-dNEWPDF`:

```
The old, written in PostScript, PDF interpreter has been removed entirely.
You should cease using -dNEWDPF as it has no effect n
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 3.0.3 --> ...
```

If I remove the text till `<?xml...` the graphic is shown properly in the browser.

Question: How do I get rid of the text during processing of the files?

I use MacTeX 2023 (TeX Live 2023) on MacOS Monterey with recent updates. Maybe editing some scripts is necessary but I don't know which one(s).

Comment: The GS option `-dNEWPDF` was only removed after the release of dvisvgm 3.0.3. As this version still uses the option, the current versions of Ghostscript print an error message -- unfortunately to `stdout` which therefore might end up in the SVG file depending on the usage of dvisvgm. As of version 3.1.1, dvisvgm omits `-dNEWPDF` for GS versions >= 10.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I know about this issue and fixed that in TeX4ht sources in December. The update is included in TeX Live, so I would expect that it is MacTeX too, but maybe it takes more time in this distro.

Anyway, the `dvisvgm_hashes` doesn't suffer from this issue. Moreover, it significantly speeds up the compilation, so if you have a lot of SVG files, the compilation will be much faster. Try this command:

```
$ make4ht -f html5+dvisvgm_hashes filename.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin and Michal, I updated my TeX Live using the `TeX Live Utility` and that fixed this issue.